# Outlook add-in is showing an empty html content upon first load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am currently building an office 365 `add-in` on outlook and upon first load the add in is showing an empty html content like so before the whole add in render correctly after couple of seconds

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

First I thought it is from the `office.then` function shown below and I tried to add a spinner before the `.then` is called but the loader didn't show, and I couldn't find the reason behind this.

Note that the add-in is developed with react and the following is the `index.js` page
Also note that the blank page is only showing on `outlook for windows` installed on a window 10 machine

```
import "office-ui-fabric-react/dist/css/fabric.min.css";
import App from "./components/App";
import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader";
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/react/lib/Icons";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../../store/store";
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import Spinner from '@atlaskit/spinner';

/* global AppCpntainer, Component, document, Office, module, React, require */
initializeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;
const title = "test";

const render = Component => {

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer>
      <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
   </AppContainer>
 </Provider>,
 document.getElementById("container")
  );
};

Office.onReady().then(function () {
 isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
});
render(App);

if (module.hot) {
 module.hot.accept("./components/App", () => {
   const NextApp = require("./components/App").default;
   render(NextApp);
  });
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Usually, a blank page indicates a difficulty of the underlying browser to render your HTML. Depending on your configuration (Outlook version + Windows version), the underlying browser could be Internet Explorer, old Microsoft Edge or new Microsoft Edge. You can determine your underlying browser using the table on this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins. Afterwards, you can debug the taskpane using the right tools. See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane

Comment: hello @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, 
this is a problem that is not related to the taskpane as i added a hardcoded loader in the default page and the loader didn't show up 
the empty html page is a kind of pre-loading state of the whole app and it is not related to the taskpage itself

Comment: Also Microsoft Edge WebView2 is installed on my machine

Comment: Did you see the native loading... text that shows up when opening the taskpane? I don't see it in your screenshot, so I think we got past that, which indicates that we made an attempt to navigate to your webpage.